# cursor index out of bound exception 0 android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have developed an android application which has content of a little book.. the application have an option of " continue reading" which used when " onback pressed" and " on pause" it stores the page and other info on shared preferences and retrieve them when pressing continue reading... however it shows" cursor index out of bounds exception" index 0 requested with size of 0 when using this option and force closes the app. i want it to remain for a while at least...
the codes are working fine in other application but here it shows exception

here is what happens to clarify the problem:

1 : normally install the apk file on device and open a text to read.

2: user press back button and goes to other parts of the application like setting or....

3: user press " continue reading" BEFORE CLOSING THE APP" app can retrieve what ever he was reading.

4: user closes the app.

5: opens it again and press "continue reading"

6:app cant retrieve the text and force closes.

or:

1:run the app from eclipse in emulator .

2:it does everything ok as long as the code is opene and run from eclipse.

3:shutdown the emulator or disconnect from eclips.

4:run the emulator.

5:open the app and press "continue reading".

6:force close.

here is my "TextShow" class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
load(book,name,Page2);
}
private void load(String sea,String Name,int page3){
db.open();
titr.setText(Name);
matn.setText(db.main_display("content", sea, Name, page3));
page.setText("page"+ Page2 + "from"+ Page1);
db.close();
}

public void onBackPressed() {

SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("cont",        0);
Editor ed=sp.edit();
ed.clear();
ed.putString("book", book);
ed.putString("name", name);
ed.putInt("page",Page1);
ed.commit();
finish();

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
SharedPreference sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("cont", 0);
Editor ed=sp.edit();
ed.clear();
ed.putString("book", book);
ed.putString("name", name);
ed.putInt("page",Page1);
ed.commit();
super.onPause();
}
```

here is my Main class:

```
ImageView cont=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cont);
cont.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("cont", 0);
    if(sp.getString("name", "*")!="*"){
        Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,TextShown.class);
        i.putExtra("book",sp.getString("book", "*"));
        i.putExtra("name",sp.getString("name", "*"));
        i.putExtra("page",sp.getInt("page", 0)+"");
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "there is no ending point", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }

    });
```

here is my database class...method for retrieving the text :

```
public String main_display(String table,String sea,String name,int page){
    Cursor cu=mydb.rawQuery("select * from "+table+" where BookName='"+sea+"' and StoryName='"+name+"' and Page="+page, null);
    cu.moveToFirst();
    String s=cu.getString(4);
    return s;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to see if cursor has items:

```
if (cu.moveToFirst()) {
    String s=cu.getString(4);
} else {
    Log.e("TAG", "Cursor empty!");
}
```

Comment: this method of database class works fine with out checking the cursor when normally the user wants to see the text.. and this is the exact method used for retrieving the left point and it returns index=0

Comment: @parisa.JT: how much columns database table have?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK about 8... (0-7)

Answer (score 1):

The exception says, that the data at index 4 could not be found, because it is not a valid index. Please note, that indexes starts from 0.

Here are some general improvements to avoid suche mistakes:

1.) You should not use hard coded indexes when retrieving data from cursor, because you can easily messed up them. Instead of that you should create a class, which simply holds the column names as string constants. Then you can define your table as follows:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + LoginColumns.TABLE_NAME + "(" + LoginColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, "
    + LoginColumns.KEY_LOGIN_ABCOCOE + " VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, "
    + LoginColumns.KEY_LOGIN_VALID + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
```

2.) You should always add a check to see if the cursor has items and use the column names instead of the plain index.

```
public String main_display(String table,String sea,String name,int page){
    Cursor cu=mydb.rawQuery("select * from "+table+" where                               BookName='"+sea+"' and StoryName='"+name+"' and Page="+page, null);
    if (cu.moveToFirst()){
        // just an example
        String s=cu.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginColumns.KEY_LOGIN_ABCOCOE)
        return s;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If this does not fix your problem, please provide some more information such as stacktrace etc.

Comment: it is very wierd the application and " continue reading" works fine when you open the application and use it as long as you haven't closed it...the problem is when you exit the app and reopen it and it is not working...i created separate class for continue reading and another method in database class but the problem remains

Comment: You call the load()-method in your onCreate()-Method of your Activity and close the cursor immediatly. So, the cursor can't be used anymore. Try to close your cursor in the onDestory()-Method, and everything should work fine.

Comment: maybe i couldn't make myself clear.. here is what happens to my application: 1 : normally install the apk file on device and open a text to read.   2: user press back button and goes to other parts of the application like setting or....    3: user press " continue reading" BEFORE CLOSING THE APP" app can retrieve what ever he was reading.       4: user closes the app.        5: opens it again and press "continue reading"         6:app cant retrieve the text and force closes.